# How should we deal with edits that 'evolved' a question?

Tags: discussion, editing

I just ran into a proposed edit to [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/139950/33287) in the review queue. The edit seemed reasonable on the surface - there was some dead text from an image link that had been partially removed on a previous edit.

But when I dug into it, I was really uncertain about the whole thing. The question 'evolved' with a insertions, changes & deletions as it was being worked out. I suspect some of the alteration probably shouldn't have been made, but given the question as it is now, how should it be dealt with? There doesn't seem to be a good single point to roll it back to, but leaving it as it is seems to leave it in a state that's less useful to other who might have run into the same problem.

Comment: FWIW, the proposed edit is meaningless. I doesn't make the post easier to read; it even makes it _harder_ because it removes the possibility to click on the image and see it full size, which is much useful in some situations.

Comment: Oh! You're right. I missed that; when I looked at the side-by-side, I didn't catch that the image outline color was different. Aside from judging the most recent proposed change (which I now think should be rejected), I'm still interested to know what to do with the rest of the question.

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case, the question has two answers that have been written/edited before a certain number of additional edits have been made, and one of them has been accepted. You've probably concluded that the edits made after those answers have been posted are not needed.

In this situation I'd remove the "Edit #:" *"labels"* and make sure the question feels "whole", and make sure that the text "fits" what the Answers propose. Kind of like *Jeopardy!* where you have to figure the question to the answer given.

On a final note, I would keep the last part where they show their results; it's not part of the question, nor does it give an answer, but letting people show off their work and sharing their happiness resulting in them solving their issue is good for them

---

In general, a question that has a lot of "Edit #:" should be edited in a way that makes it whole and makes it relevant to the actual problem the user is trying to have solved. If an edit or a chunk of code adds more noise that signal, it should be removed.

Again, in general, if the edits and additions add so much confusion that it's now hard to figure out the core of the issue, votes should be applied on the question to help convince the user to figure of a better way to ask the question.